# SASL PLAIN authentication failed: another step is needed in authentication

Tags: postfix, tls, sasl

I have one host (rhea) where I have installed a postfix to relay the emails from my home server (tronics24), which is on a DSL connection.

I have generated self-signed certificates: (on rhea)

```
touch smtpd.key
chmod 600 smtpd.key
openssl genrsa 1024 > smtpd.key
openssl req -new -key smtpd.key -x509 -days 3650 -out smtpd.crt
openssl req -new -x509 -extensions v3_ca -keyout cakey.pem -out cacert.pem -days 3650
sudo mv smtpd.key /etc/ssl/private/
sudo mv smtpd.crt /etc/ssl/certs/
sudo mv cakey.pem /etc/ssl/private/
sudo mv cacert.pem /etc/ssl/certs/
```

I have tested the certificates:

```
root@rhea:~# openssl s_client -showcerts -cert /etc/ssl/certs/smtpd.crt -key /etc/ssl/private/smtpd.key -starttls smtp -CAfile /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem -connect localhost:25
```

To which postfix replies (/var/log/mail.log):

```
Apr 26 02:44:36 rhea postfix/smtpd[28778]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Apr 26 02:44:36 rhea postfix/smtpd[28778]: setting up TLS connection from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Apr 26 02:44:37 rhea postfix/smtpd[28778]: Anonymous TLS connection established from localhost[127.0.0.1]: TLSv1 with cipher DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA (256/256 bits)
```

I have tested SASL authorization:

```
root@rhea:~# testsaslauthd -u <my-user> -p <my-pass>
0: OK "Success."
```

Up to here everything looks fine. Now I try to connect from my home server. First, I generate the authentication string:

```
printf '<my-user>\0<my-user>\0<my-pass>' | mmencode
dummydummy...==

myuser@tronics24 ~ » openssl s_client -starttls smtp -host rhea.<my-domain>.net -port 25
...
250 DSN
ehlo localhost
250-<mydomain>.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN
250-AUTH=LOGIN PLAIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
AUTH PLAIN dummydummy
535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: another step is needed in authentication
```

Postfix in rhea is telling me the same thing:

```
Apr 26 02:17:10 rhea postfix/smtpd[11085]: connect from ip-82-143-145-145.myispdomain.com[82.143.145.145]
Apr 26 02:17:10 rhea postfix/smtpd[11085]: setting up TLS connection from ip-82-143-145-145.myispdomain.com[82.143.145.145]
Apr 26 02:17:10 rhea postfix/smtpd[11085]: Anonymous TLS connection established from ip-82-143-145-145.myispdomain.com[82.143.145.145]: TLSv1 with cipher DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA (256/256 bits)
Apr 26 02:17:19 rhea postfix/smtpd[11085]: warning: ip-82-143-145-145.myispdomain.com[82.143.145.145]: SASL PLAIN authentication failed: another step is needed in authentication
Apr 26 02:17:35 rhea postfix/smtpd[11085]: lost connection after AUTH from ip-82-143-145-145.myispdomain.com[82.143.145.145]
Apr 26 02:17:35 rhea postfix/smtpd[11085]: disconnect from ip-82-143-145-145.myispdomain.com[82.143.145.145]
```

I am very confused about this, and do not know what else to look for. Do you have any idea what else should I verify?

## EDIT

As requested, I am posting the postfix configuration:

```
# Let's check the postconf configuration
root@rhea:~# postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
config_directory = /etc/postfix
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = rhea.<my-domain>.net, localhost.<my-domain>.net, localhost
myhostname = rhea.<my-domain>.net
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 82.143.145.145
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost = 
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = 
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/smtpd.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/smtpd.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_use_tls = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
```

The output of `postconf -a`:

```
root@rhea:~# postconf -a
cyrus
dovecot
```

This is the output of `saslfinger -s`:

```
root@rhea:~# saslfinger -s
saslfinger - postfix Cyrus sasl configuration Thu Apr 26 10:34:57 CEST 2012
version: 1.0.4
mode: server-side SMTP AUTH

-- basics --
Postfix: 2.5.1
System: Ubuntu 8.04.4 LTS (server)
Linux rhea.<my-domain>.net 2.6.32.2-xxxx-grs-ipv4-32 #1 SMP Tue Dec 29 14:41:18 UTC 2009 i686 GNU/Linux

server    : rps
ip        : 178.52.127.32
hostname  : rhea.<my-domain>.net

-- smtpd is linked to --
    libsasl2.so.2 => /usr/lib/libsasl2.so.2 (0xb7593000)

-- active SMTP AUTH and TLS parameters for smtpd --
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = 
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/smtpd.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/smtpd.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_use_tls = yes


-- listing of /usr/lib/sasl2 --
total 716
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 2011-06-28 10:21 .
drwxr-xr-x 70 root root 36864 2011-06-22 17:30 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 13568 2009-06-23 21:14 libanonymous.a
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   862 2009-06-23 21:14 libanonymous.la
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 12984 2009-06-23 21:14 libanonymous.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 12984 2009-06-23 21:14 libanonymous.so.2
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 12984 2009-06-23 21:14 libanonymous.so.2.0.22
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 15834 2009-06-23 21:14 libcrammd5.a
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   848 2009-06-23 21:14 libcrammd5.la
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 15320 2009-06-23 21:14 libcrammd5.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 15320 2009-06-23 21:14 libcrammd5.so.2
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 15320 2009-06-23 21:14 libcrammd5.so.2.0.22
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 46332 2009-06-23 21:14 libdigestmd5.a
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   871 2009-06-23 21:14 libdigestmd5.la
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 43020 2009-06-23 21:14 libdigestmd5.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 43020 2009-06-23 21:14 libdigestmd5.so.2
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 43020 2009-06-23 21:14 libdigestmd5.so.2.0.22
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 13574 2009-06-23 21:14 liblogin.a
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   842 2009-06-23 21:14 liblogin.la
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 13268 2009-06-23 21:14 liblogin.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 13268 2009-06-23 21:14 liblogin.so.2
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 13268 2009-06-23 21:14 liblogin.so.2.0.22
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 30016 2009-06-23 21:14 libntlm.a
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   836 2009-06-23 21:14 libntlm.la
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 29236 2009-06-23 21:14 libntlm.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 29236 2009-06-23 21:14 libntlm.so.2
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 29236 2009-06-23 21:14 libntlm.so.2.0.22
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 13798 2009-06-23 21:14 libplain.a
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   842 2009-06-23 21:14 libplain.la
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 13396 2009-06-23 21:14 libplain.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 13396 2009-06-23 21:14 libplain.so.2
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 13396 2009-06-23 21:14 libplain.so.2.0.22
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 22126 2009-06-23 21:14 libsasldb.a
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   873 2009-06-23 21:14 libsasldb.la
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 18080 2009-06-23 21:14 libsasldb.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 18080 2009-06-23 21:14 libsasldb.so.2
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 18080 2009-06-23 21:14 libsasldb.so.2.0.22

-- listing of /etc/postfix/sasl --
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2011-07-01 11:19 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 2012-04-26 10:10 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   50 2011-07-01 11:19 smtpd.conf




-- content of /etc/postfix/sasl/smtpd.conf --
pwcheck_method: saslauthd
mech_list: plain login


-- content of /etc/postfix/sasl/smtpd.conf --
pwcheck_method: saslauthd
mech_list: plain login



-- active services in /etc/postfix/master.cf --
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
pickup    fifo  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
    -o smtp_fallback_relay=
showq     unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -   n   n   -   2   pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}

-- mechanisms on localhost --
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN
250-AUTH=LOGIN PLAIN


-- end of saslfinger output --
```

Comment: What is the postfix version, what are you using for SASL and why is it not dovecot, include *relevant* logs of a failed message and the output of `postconf -n` with your post.

Comment: Thnaks. As requested, I have added some details about configuration. What 'relevant logs' do you have in mind? I have googled intensively, but part of my problem is that I am not aware of which subsystems must be checked, so I am not sure where to look for problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To relay mail from a client, use submission, not plain SMTP.

You should configure postfix to reject submission on port 25 (port 25 is only for MTA <-> MTA relay).

See the commented submission example in master.cf for details; clients should connect to port 587 (submission) using STARTTLS and LOGIN authentication.

All other mail may be rejected on submission, i.e. you set

```
-o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
```

on the submission listener.

Then test with an *actual* client.

Comment: Actually, I want to relay emails from my home postfix daemon, via the postfix service in rhea.

Comment: Then why does this require SASL ?

Comment: Good question! I said I am a bit confused. Actually, what I want is to make sure that the relaying postfix (rhea) only relays email comming from my homeserver postfix. Do you know what is the simplest solution to set this up?

Comment: IP restriction ;)

Comment: ...Errrwut ? :)

Comment: Yea, because Comcast thinks everyone is an idiot.  And monopolies suck.

Answer (score 0):

This is ten years later, but sometimes for debugging you still need the same commands. In my case:

```
`openssl s_client -starttls smtp -quiet -crlf -connect server-name:587`
```

which resulted in the same error (after `EHLO test`):

```
`535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: another step is needed in authentication`
```

I managed to find the problem in my case: the string encoding user name and password was not complete, copy-pasting automatically excluded the trailing non-alphanumeric characters (in my case: '='). So, simple check before getting into details on SASL and components: check your inputs are complete.